# Protocol error when using Net:SSH:Perl module

Tags: perl, unix, ssh, rhel

I have a script that uses Net::SSH:Perl module. It is able to ssh to RHEL6.9 hosts but not RHEL7.4 hosts. I get the following error:

Protocol error: expected packet type 91, got 80 at /Net/SSH/Perl/Packet.pm line 221

How do I remedy this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [simple search for the error message](https://www.google.com/search?q=Protocol+error%3A+expected+packet+type+91%2C+got+80+at+%2FNet%2FSSH%2FPerl%2FPacket.pm) gives [this post from 2016](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1144748) and [this bug report from 2016](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=118291) which both indicate that the issue was fixed in version 2.01 of the module, released in 10/2016. Thus, you are probably using an older version and need to upgrade.